# EEA family permit for UK

Tags: uk-visa

I am Chinese. My husband is Irish. We are living together in China. When I apply for the EEA family permit. Do we need to provide any financial support documents ?

Comment: We are planning to move to the UK

Answer (score 1):

No.  As an EU citizen, your husband (currently) has the (almost) absolute right to move to the UK and bring his family with him.  Obtaining an EEA family permit is required to be quick, easy, and cheap.

Notes on parenthesized comments:

"Almost": There are a few exceptions; the UK can decide to exclude serious criminals (although I believe it currently doesn't).

"Currently": It is hard to believe that you haven't heard about Brexit.  Nobody knows at the moment what will happen after Brexit.  If you have all moved by 29th March, you will *probably* be OK even if a no-deal Brexit happens.  If a deal happens, you need to move by the end of the transition period (currently end of 2020).

You are in a particularly strong position in that your husband is Irish.  Even after Brexit, it is very likely that Irish citizens will have the same immigration rights to the UK as UK citizens.  Sadly, that means you *will* need to demonstrate that he can support you (and the application will be much more expensive).

Comment: Thank you !  Your answer is helpful !  Also, I would like to ask, normally,  how long it takes to get the EEA family permit after we hand in the application documents ?

Comment: A quick search found: https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/paris-france/other-non-settlement-visas/eea-family-permits  which suggests most applications are decided in two weeks.  No data from Beijing though.  I don't know if that is "no data" or "you can't apply from there".

Comment: I suspect that there is indeed a threshold of seriousness beyond which the UK would exclude someone from free movement rights, but I don't know what that is.  Under EU law it's pretty clear though that the UK would have to show a threat to public safety.  A record of serious crime by itself is not sufficient.  If there's no deal, will there be a transition period? I had thought not, but haven't looked at it closely enough to be certain.

Comment: @phoog If there is literally "no deal", there will be no transition period - which is why my mention of the transition period was predicated on a deal.

Comment: Oh I see.  I must have skipped a few words, since I read "if a no-deal Brexit happens you will need to move by the end of the transition period."